# Spring-data-neo4j and compatibility with Scala

Tags: scala, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I suspect that **Spring-data-neo4j 2.1.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT** isn't really compatible with some versions of **Scala**.

I use scala 2.10.0 and using a Play! web application based on scala 2.10.0 too.

While running a test involving a Neo4jTemplate autowired by Spring, I obtain this error:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
    with name 'mappingInfrastructure' defined in class 
    org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; 
    nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     
scala.collection.JavaConverters$.mapAsScalaMapConverter(Ljava/util/Map;)Lscala/collection/JavaConverters$AsScala
```

Does a fix exist or would be scheduled?

Comment: I've just downloaded neo4j1.9M04 and now that works :)

Comment: Yes Scala 2.10 support was just released with Neo4j 1.9.M04 on Friday.

Comment: @Michael Hunger Excellent! If I well understand, it is Cypher that has just been updated to Scala 2.10.  Thanks Michael :)

Comment: Yup that's correct, feel free to test it out and report issues.